# Loading SparkR within RStudio: Err [could not find function "launchBackend"]

Tags: rstudio, sparkr

Having trouble loading `SparkR` into my `RStudio`. When I try to load a spark context, I get the error:

> Could not find function "launchBackend."

I can get `sparkR` working on my terminal shell, but that's also because I don't have to load a spark context (it seems like it's already there). Any help?

```
Sys.setenv(SPARK_HOME="~/spark-1.4.1")
.libPaths(c(file.path(Sys.getenv("SPARK_HOME"), "R", "lib"), .libPaths()))
library(SparkR)
sc <- sparkR.init(master = "local")
sqlContext <- sparkRSQL.init(sc)
```

Answer (score 4):

One thing which might help is to type the full path in. R doesn't expand the tilde.

Instead of:

```
Sys.setenv(SPARK_HOME="~/spark-1.4.1")
```

Something like this:

```
Sys.setenv(SPARK_HOME="/home/spark-1.4.1")
```